# Trouble only combining 2 flex columns while leaving the 3rd alone

Tags: css, flexbox

I am currently using flex to control the layout of my website. There is one 'container' that has display:flex, and three flex columns inside. This is illustrated below. What I'd like to do, is as the screen width gets smaller, I'd like to use CSS to change the order (which I know how to do), but also combine two columns leaving one to be seperate (also illustrated below). How would one do this? I can change the direction of the flex so that they are vertical, but I don't want the third column included.

```
How it is now:                        How I want it :)
|------|  |------|  |------|         |------|  |------|
|      |  |      |  |      |         |  A   |  |  B   |
|  A   |  |  B   |  |  C   |         --------  |      |
|      |  |      |  |      |         |------|  --------
--------  --------  --------         |  C   |  
                                     --------
```

As you can see, I want the C block to change order, and stack under A while leaving B alone.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: please can you show your current css and html - please see how to create a [MCVE]

Comment: Can _B_ be higher than _A_? .... meaning if content in _B_ grows, should it grow vertically independently from _A_ and _C_?

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```css
.item {
  width: 33.33%;
  height: 200px;
  background: red;
  border: solid 2px #000;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 1000px) {
  .item {
    width: 50%;
  }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .item {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could toggle `flex-wrap` between `wrap` and `nowrap`.

```css
.flex {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.flex > div {
  flex-basis: 50%;
}
@media ( min-width: 650px ) {
  .flex {
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="flex">
  <div>A</div>
  <div>B</div>
  <div>C</div>
</div>
```